# Why is my display: inline-block; behaving like a block?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to get my boxes of paragraphs to appear next to each other in the given container, but when I set them to display: inline-block; they still display as if they were set to display: block;

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#container section {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app-mc.css">
  <title>Display</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <section>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa deserunt distinctio vel quis mollitia illum
        minima qui harum architecto praesentium, iure, a obcaecati, ipsam aliquam ut totam excepturi vero enim!</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa deserunt distinctio vel quis mollitia illum
        minima qui harum architecto praesentium, iure, a obcaecati, ipsam aliquam ut totam excepturi vero enim!</p>
    </section>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: both together have more than 800px width placed inside 50% container so your screen need to be more than 1600px width to see them next to each other

Comment: I would also avoid setting concrete pixel sizes, instead I would suggest using flex layouts.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you applied a fixed width for the inline-blocks (400px) that won't fit into the parent element twice. Use a percentage width instead:

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#container section {
  width: 48.5%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app-mc.css">
  <title>Display</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <section>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa deserunt distinctio vel quis mollitia illum
        minima qui harum architecto praesentium, iure, a obcaecati, ipsam aliquam ut totam excepturi vero enim!</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa deserunt distinctio vel quis mollitia illum
        minima qui harum architecto praesentium, iure, a obcaecati, ipsam aliquam ut totam excepturi vero enim!</p>
    </section>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```